# "permission denied" for pg_dump output file

Tags: database, postgresql, command-line, backup, pg-dump

i used below command to backup my database

`sudo -u user_name pg_dump dbName -f /home ..../someWhere/db.sql`

but it gives me this :

`pg_dump: [archiver] could not open output file "/home ..../someWhere/db.sql": Permission denied`

after googling this issue i find that i must backup my data under the `/tmp` path , but doesn't work

how can i resolve this issue ?

thanks in advance,

---

i am using Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Comment: This looks like a permission issue. Are you able to manually create a file like "/home ..../someWhere/db.sql" from command prompt?

Comment: thanks @Jayadevan , yes i could to create file manually using `touch` command

Comment: @MostafaJamareh Are you able to create the file using `touch` **using the same sudo command** though? What is "user_name"? *Why* are you `sudo`ing to another user to do the dump?

Comment: You could also try sudo -u user_name psql. Then, from psql. try to execute the same touch command. `postgres=# \! touch /tmp/myfile.txt`
`postgres=# \! ls -l /tmp/myfile.txt`
-rw-rw-r-- 1 postgres postgres 0 Jan 31 10:23 /tmp/myfile.txt

Comment: @CraigRinger what is "user_name"? , it is a postgresql user_name , i want to connect to postgres user to dump

Comment: @Jayadevan yes i could create myFile.txt from psql

Comment: thanks @Jayadevan it worked when i executed the `pg_dump` command from `psql`

Comment: @MostafaJamareh It makes no sense to "connect to" a user to run `pg_dump`. `pg_dump` is a shell command, not a PostgreSQL command. If you mean you want to switch to the user, i.e. you really meant `sudo -u postgres pg_dump ...`, **why didn't you say so**?

Comment: @CraigRinger when i try it without `sudo -u user_name` it gives me this `pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "dbName" failed: FATAL:  role "user_name" does not exist`

Comment: @MostafaJamareh Well, clearly there's no PostgreSQL user named `user_name`. So create one, or specify a different user to connect as. I think you really need to go read the client authentication chapter of the user manual, or possibly the tutorial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try `pg_dump` from `psql command-line` as below:

```
postgres=# \! pg_dump dbName -f /home ..../someWhere/db.sql
```

Comment: I never had to do this before on any machine.  It "just worked."  What changed?  How do I change it back?

Answer (score 17):

It looks like your pg_dump is working fine, but it is having problems opening the output file as the sudo user.  Just guessing, but, if you do the redirection as the user (presumably the one running the pg_dump command) id, that should do it, that is:

sudo -u user_name pg_dump dbName > /home ..../someWhere/db.sql

Using this technique your pg_dump will run as the postgres user (assuming that is who user_name is) and the file being written in /home... will be written using the permission of the user running the command (this user might have different permissions than the postgres user).

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody else lands here like I did, be aware that **`pg_dump` shows this error too if the folder doesn't exist**. In that case, just create the directory beforehand using `mkdir -p folder_name`.

Answer (score 1):

Do it from psql command line like below

```
-bash-4.1$ pg_dump -Fp dbName -f /home ..../someWhere/db.sql &
```

**-F**  selects the format of the output in which **p** is Output a plain-text SQL script file

and **&** at the end will run your backup in the background.