# pg_dump in docker: "could not open output file" "protocol error"

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-machine, pg-dump

Starting a docker postgresql container to dump a database using `pg_dump` to a mounted volume results in:

```
could not open output file "blah": protocol error
```

The `protocol error` is different from the `permission denied` issue as discussed  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457456/permission-denied-for-pg-dump-output-file) for instance. What does this error mean? There is no existing file in the mounted volume.

I'm using docker-machine on OSX.

Comment: I had a similar problem in Windows. The filename had a timestamp with a colon in it, which is an illegal character in Windows.

Comment: You are right! I had the same issue with docker-machine on OSX. I'll update the answer. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. It turned out my filename had a colon in it, which is not allowed with docker-machine on OSX. I initially thought it was a permission issue that can be solved by using starting the container in `privileged` model [as described here](https://docker-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/hostconfig/).